# Is it true that cold climate will make the conditions of prostatitis worse?

Tags: prostatitis

I find my symptoms such as frequent urination will become worse in cold days

Comment: Your question is  oftopic. See your doctor.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. [For a various number of reasons outlined in this excellent post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), we can not - and will not - give personal medical advice. If you have any question regarding your personal health, you should visit a GP or a specialist of your choice. For further information which is on-topic or not, you can visit the [How To Ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [meta]. [Here is a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explaining question closure.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. Prostatitis or not, you will naturally urinate more in lower temperature. https://www.scienceabc.com/humans/why-do-we-urinate-more-when-were-cold.html Frequent urination would probably makes you suffer more.

Answer (score -1):

With temperature dropping, the sympathetic nerve become more exciting. The prostate gland shrinks while crypt and blood vessel expands. This results in chronic congestion, which increases the internal pressure within the urethra and the risk of a backward flow.

The change of the urethra intensifies the blockage of prostate fluid and it triggers prostatitis with symptoms of:

- frequent and urgent urination
- painful urination
- abdominal pain
- pain in testicles

Comment: -1: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].